# Second linked stylesheet has no effect

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems linking a second stylesheet to my HTML document, and cannot find the (hopefully painfully obvious) problem.

I'm linking stylesheets in the head thus:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css" type="text/css" media="all" title="Global styles" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="all" title="IE Overrides" charset="utf-8">
```

The problem is, the seconds stylesheet has no effect what so ever. Reversing their order proves this as well.

For testing, I put in a rule in the second stylesheet to make the body background red, even tried adding `!important`, but to no avail.

```
/* Global CSS */
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* IE CSS */
body {
    background-color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Firebug net panel shows that both stylesheets do load, and the style panel shows me the styles in both of them, but the rules in the latter just don't do squat.

This has left me baffled, since it is very, very basic stuff, which I've previously done successfully hundreds and hundreds of times.

Comment: You do realize IE doesn't support !important right?

Comment: Since when? (Perhaps you're referring to the bug that causes IE to handle !important wrongly, but it is supported none the less.)

But for the issue at hand it wouldn't matter anyway, since I'm including the seconds stylesheet for all browsers, until I solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the problematic page?  Will make it easier for us to diagnose..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the `title` attribute from both your `link` tags. `title` has a special meaning when used with stylesheet links, more here:

[**Alternative Style: Working With Alternate Style Sheets**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/)

Comment: You're welcome! This "feature" is totally weird and counter-intuitive and should be abolished IMO. This is impossible to know if you haven't stumbled upon it in the past.

Comment: Indeed. I've, in fact, never before utilized the `title`-attribute on `link`-tag before (slap forehead), but did now, since my new and shiny editor, E, autofilled it when using `link<tab>` autocompletion, and I foolishly assumed it wouldn't actually do anything, but just look nice and shiny.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had moved working CSS rulesets from a PHP string in the page source to an external CSS file:

From:

```
    $headCss.=
    '   <style type="text/css">
            #containBrainForHire
            {   background:url(\'/graphics/BrainForHire.png\');
                display:table;
                height:300px;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:525px;
            }
        </style>
    ';
```

To:

```
    #containBrainForHire
    {   background:url(\'/graphics/BrainForHire.png\');
        display:table;
        height:300px;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:525px;
    }
```

***NOTHING*** in the new CSS file worked until I fixed the `background` definition: The backslashes needed to escape the single quotes in the PHP string are invalid in the CSS file.

Corrected CSS file contents:

```
    #containBrainForHire
    {   background:url('/graphics/BrainForHire.png');
        display:table;
        height:300px;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:525px;
    }
```

There were **no errors reported in the error console**, just nothing in the new CSS file had any effect on the page's display.  (So much for useful debugging tools...)

I hope this saves someone else the time that it took me to recognize the problem.